# Angular 6 select: set initial value

Tags: angular, select

I have the following code

```
<select name="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option *ngFor="let r of roles" [ngValue]="r">{{r.name}}</option>
</select>
```

where roles is an Object:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"user"}, {"id": 2, "name":"admin"}]
```

and user.role is for example:

```
{"id":1, "name":"user"}
```

I want initial value to be the user.role, I've tried a lot of things like ngInit, but it didn't get the job done.

Comment: the problem is that [ngValue] is an object. So use user.role=roles[0]; (NOTE:If you use [ngValue]="r.id", you can use user.role=roles[0].id

Comment: @Eliseo, why should I? lol

Comment: it's strange that user.role was an object. I think you want that user.role was a number (1 or 2), not {id:1,name:admin}

Comment: @Eliseo I'm using Spring data jpa on my backend to get full user role, why should it be the number? It's my own object of Role class actually.

Comment: In only was trying to help you. of course you can use an object or whatever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this solution.

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-select-set-initial-value?file=src/app/app.component.html)

use [compareWith]="compareObjects" for use object in select

> component.html

```
<select name="role" [compareWith]="compareObjects" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option *ngFor="let r of roles" [ngValue]="r">{{r.name}}</option>
</select>
```

> component.ts

```
  user = {
    role: { "id": 1, "name": "user" }
  }
  roles = [
    { "id": 1, "name": "user" }, 
    { "id": 2, "name": "admin" }
  ]

  compareObjects(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    return o1.id === o2.id && o1.name === o2.name;
  }
```

Comment: too complex, it's not necesary