# Angular 6 : Select display value

Tags: typescript, select, angular6

I want to use the select component to display a list of car from a page. When the user select a car and press a button it will send the car id to the backend.

It's ok to get the list of cars, display the name of the car and retrieve the id, but when I go back on the page, I want the car selected first to be there (my API returns the right car)
I tried a few solutions with no success (this one for example: [Angular 6 select: set initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762429/angular-6-select-set-initial-value)) to display a value when I go back on the page.

```
<select name=car [(ngModel)]="model.car.name" >
<option *ngFor="let car of cars" value='{{car.id}}'>
{{car.name}}
</option>
</select>
```

Here's my ts:

```
@Input()  model: Car;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.carService.getList.pipe(
          take(1))
          .subscribe((results) => {
            this.cars = results;
          });
      }
```

How can I do?

Comment: Where shall the selected car be displayed? In a separate label or so?

Comment: same page, same place as the list, it would be considered as an initial/selected value

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `compareWith`-directive. It tells the select-element to look for the particular car. If found it will be set in the dropdown-list. But then you have to bind ngModel to the entire car object. `[(ngModel)]="model.car"`.

HTML

```
<select name=car [(ngModel)]="model.car.name" [compareWith]="compareById">
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" value='{{car.id}}'>
        {{car.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

TS

```
protected compareById(itemA: any, itemB: any): boolean {
    if (itemA === undefined && itemB === undefined) {
        return true; // show the default option
    } else if (itemA && itemB) {
        return (itemA.id === itemB.id); // show the specific option
    }
    else {
        return false; // no match found
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.